# jQuery adding classes works but removing doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and subsequently remove some classes as user clicks on the button (`.header_hamburger`), with the following jQuery code, I can add those classes (and remove one), but I am having problem to reverse my actions (removing classes and adding just one) so that the side menu (my case) I am trying toggling can vanish as the users click out.

```
<div class="header header--mic">
    <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__hamburger" id="button-add">
            <div id="box" class="nav-icon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__site-nav">
        <div class="site-nav site-nav--hidden"></div>
    </div>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on("click", ".header__hamburger", function() {
                $('div.nav-icon').addClass("nav-icon--x nav-icon--white");
                $('div.header.header--mic').addClass("header--site-nav-expanded");
                $('div.header__site-nav').addClass("header__site-nav--expanded");
                if ($('div.site-nav').hasClass("site-nav--hidden")) {
                    $('div.site-nav').removeClass("site-nav--hidden");
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: check [`$.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: There's no need for your `hasClass()` check. `removeClass()` doesn't do anything if the class doesn't exist on the element, so there's no reason to check for the class's presence before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use `toggleClass()` function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.nav-icon').addClass("nav-icon--x nav-icon--white");
  $('div.header.header--mic').addClass("header--site-nav-expanded");
  $('div.header__site-nav').addClass("header__site-nav--expanded");
  $('div.site-nav').toggleClass("site-nav--hidden");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

as i see you need to show and hide an element 
you can do it like this

```
$(".site-nav--hidden").hide();

 $(".site-nav--hidden").show();
```